# How to take average of total time spent by specific mac address in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i have a mongodb collection which is shown below

```
_id                       | MAC               | Entry_Time              | Exit_time 
5d4aa86dacadb34b5841bbf1  | 00:a0:00:00:18:c8 | 2019-08-07 10:31:09.000 | 2019-08-07 11:52:57.000
5d4abbff19dc294b77ab6ade  | 00:a0:00:00:18:c8 | 2019-08-07 11:54:38.000 | 2019-08-07 12:06:27.000
```

What i want to do is get the avg time spent by a specific mac 
i have tried something that is given below i don't think its working fine.Kindly help me formulate a query which will give me the desired result

```
 db.getCollection("user_presence").aggregate(
{$match:
    {
        MAC: '00:a0:00:00:18:c8'
    }
},
{$project:
    { 

                    totalHourSpent:{$divide : [{$subtract: ["$Exit_time","$Entry_Time"]}, 3600000]}
    }
},
{$group:
    {
        _id:"$MAC",
        avg_time_spent: {$avg:
           "$totalHourSpent"
         }
    }
}
)
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: what kind of result you are looking for?